# Kali Linux 2.0 broken, doesn't boot

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

I have a Macbook Pro with a partition of Kali Linux Sana 2.0 on the macintosh hard drive. I haven't used it for a while but today I decided to boot into it.

It booted as usual, I logged in etc. and then I opened terminal and ran `apt-get update`. After that was done I ran `apt-get upgrade`.

This is where I messed up, everything downloaded and it was dpkg'ing a bunch of things it had downloaded, but then it got stuck for about 5 minutes and I got really annoyed so I clicked <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, to cancel the upgrade, but nothing happened, so then I decided to restart the machine. But when it has booted up it brought me to a grey screen with a login tab in the center.

I logged in as usual but then the screen turned black, and after about a minute a white screen with the words "oh no something has gone wrong a problem has occurred and the system can't recover" and there was nothing else on the screen except a Logout button which just restarts Kali and the process repeats.

I have looked for a solution and the only thing I have found is to click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>(orF2) and to continue some terminal commands, but nothing came up as in the tutorials. Now I don't know what to do.

I don't even care if I will have to completely reinstall Kali Linux, but I need a solution because now I have a 40GB partition on my mac which is just broken Kali Linux.

Comment: For formatting and machine recovery: 1. use kali linux in live mode
2. start gparted and format all the disks partitions (make sure you boot flaag that partition in which you will be installing OSX .)
3. follow instructions given on [this page](http://goo.gl/6l3WqW) for booting up your usb drive with OSX and performing a clean install.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I was able to fix this issue on my machine with Kali running in a VM:

1. Turn on the machine
2. When GRUB loads select **Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux**
3. Select **Kali GNU/Linux, with ...(recovery mode)**
4. When prompted, enter your root password
5. Issue the following command `dpkg --configure -a`
6. Wait for `dpkg` to reconfigure and sort itself out
7. You should now be able to boot back into a working version of Kali

Comment: I've version 2017.1 of Kali installed In VBox and I've run upgrade and it break the installation, this fixed the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, `dpkg --configure -a` doesn't work for me.

Comment: This worked for me on 4.16.0

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago when upgrading the packages in my Kali 2.0 system, and ended up working around it by installing LightDM. You won't have a gorgeous login interface, but it should work.

Comment: The problem is I cant get into Kali. After the grey login screen Kali Linux just crashes. Can you please explain what exactly I should do.

Comment: Try to access the tty interface by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2, you should enter into a shell-only interface. Log in and then install lightdm via aptitude, by typing "sudo aptitude install lightdm". When it installs, it will ask you to set the default window and logon manager, set LightDM as default and exit. Then reboot, you should be able to login via GUI now

Comment: This is the problem, when I click Cntrl+Alt+F2 nothing happens. I don't understand if that is because I am on a mac or because my problem is worse than yours.

Comment: Does your PC reboot after the grey screen ? Or does it stuck in a pre-boot screen with an error complaining about the i915 driver ? If not you should be able to access the shell interface. Maybe in my case only Gnome crashes, when in yours the entire system does...

Comment: It just reboots, and then the same login popup appears. After I log in the "oh no something has gone wrong a problem has occurred and the system can't recover" error message comes up and a Logout button, that is it. Cntrl Alt F2 doesn't work.

Comment: This, (https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26637-Can-t-login-after-the-upgrade-to-Kali-linux-2-0/) is pretty similar to your situation an for those users lightdm fixed it. If it doesn't work and you can't access the command line logon interface, i'd suggest you to clean install Kali again

Comment: Okay, I have ended up reinstalling Kali freshly as I could not be bothered figuring out the problem. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm sorry but i couldn't help you anymore...

Comment: Blessings upon your keyboard and your mouse!