# Kali Linux 2016.1 Command buffer error

Tags: kali-linux

I installed Kali 2016.1 (Rolling) version in VMWare Workstation. After installation of Kali and installing VMWare Tools, I noticed that the kernel release version was kali-4.3.0. I proceeded with upgrading it to a later version by modifying the /etc/apt/sources.list file with the URL to the rolling repo:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
reboot
```

The upgrade appears to have happened successfully, however, the reboot simply ends up with a black screen. I changed to a tty screen by pressing ctrl+Alt+F3 and then typed in

```
service gdm3 restart
```

I am still left with a black screen error.

I noticed that the dmesg log file is full of the following error messages:

```
[drm:vmw_cmdbuf_work_func [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Command buffer error.
```

I do notice that the kernel version has upgraded as running

```
uname -r
```

returns

```
4.6.0-kali1-686-pae
```

Any pointers on what could be happening here?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

This Tip taken (from Pavel Rizzo): [Kali Linux 2.0 broken, doesn't boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259424/kali-linux-2-0-broken-doesnt-boot)

It appears that one way to work around this issue is to install lightdm by dropping to the shell (tty2 - ctrl + alt + F2) and typing in:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Choosing lightdm as default and then

```
sudo reboot
```

appears to bring up the kali login screen as GUI.

Answer (score 0):

On grub screen press e to open grub parameters. Replace `quiet` with `nomodeset quiet splash`. To make this change permanent once you reach desktop, edit the same in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Can you explain *why* this would solve the problem?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.